# Understanding computer organisation and architecture

Tags: digital-logic, computer-architecture

What are some of the user friendly books for "computer organisation and architechture" which are best for self study. Such a text that one can grasps the big picture, and understandhow various things are fitting with each other.

Topics include: machine instructions and addressing modes, ALU and data path , cpu control design, memory interface, I/o interface (interrupt and DMA mode), instruction pipelining, cache and main memory.

Thanks

Answer (score 4):

I suggest you to read the Hennessy & Patterson book on computer architecture "Computer Organization and Design: the Hardware/Software Interface".

It is widely use in bachelor courses on computer architecture around the world. It is well written and easy to follow. Throughout the book the authors use a MIPS pipeline to explain the concepts that they introduce.

Comment: And just to add to the answer you can also go for " Computer Architecture: A quantitative approach" by the same authors. It is a bit advanced.